# gerar um json php

Tags: php, json

ola

estou com um problema acredito que me podem ajudar,
é o seguinte preciso de ter um json deste genero

```
    {
"nodes":[
{"name":"Barry"},
{"name":"Frodo"},
{"name":"Elvis"},
{"name":"Sarah"},
{"name":"Alice"}
],
"links":[
{"source":"Barry","target":"Elvis","value":2},
{"source":"Frodo","target":"Elvis","value":2},
{"source":"Frodo","target":"Sarah","value":2},
{"source":"Barry","target":"Alice","value":2},
{"source":"Elvis","target":"Sarah","value":2},
{"source":"Elvis","target":"Alice","value":2},
{"source":"Sarah","target":"Alice","value":4}
]}
```

estou a gerar desta forma

```
             $stmt->execute();
        $nodes = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $stmptrabalho->execute();
            $links = $stmptrabalho->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
          $array = array(
        'nodes' => $nodes,
        'links' => $links
    );
$fp = fopen('json.json', 'w');
fwrite($fp, json_encode($array,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));
fclose($fp);
```

gera-me o ficheiro só que fica tudo na mesma linha existe alguma forma de guardar como o ficheiro acima outra coisa que  me acontece é o value aparecer com "no valor e nao devia"´

resultado nova

```
 "nodes": [
    {
        "name": "Alentejo Central"
    },
    {
        "name": "Alentejo Litoral"
    },
    {
        "name": "Algarve"
    },
    {
        "name": "Alto Alentejo"
    },
    {
        "name": "Alto Trás-os-Montes"
    },
    {
        "name": "Ave"
    },
    {
        "name": "Baixo Alentejo"
    },
    {
        "name": "Baixo Mondego"
    },
    {
        "name": "Baixo Vouga"
    },
    {
        "name": "Beira Interior Norte"
    },
    {
        "name": "Beira Interior Sul"
    },
    {
        "name": "Cávado"
    },
    {
        "name": "Cova da Beira"
    },
    {
        "name": "Dão-Lafões"
    },
    {
        "name": "Douro"
    },
    {
        "name": "Entre Douro e Vouga"
    },
    {
        "name": "Estrangeiro"
    },
    {
        "name": "Grande Lisboa"
    },
    {
        "name": "Grande Porto"
    },
    {
        "name": "Lezíria do Tejo"
    },
    {
        "name": "Médio Tejo"
    },
    {
        "name": "Minho-Lima"
    },
    {
        "name": "nao se aplica"
    },
    {
        "name": "Não se aplica"
    },
    {
        "name": "Oeste"
    },
    {
        "name": "Península de Setúbal"
    },
    {
        "name": "Pinhal Interior Norte"
    },
    {
        "name": "Pinhal Interior Sul"
    },
    {
        "name": "Pinhal Litoral"
    },
    {
        "name": "Região Autónoma da Madeira"
    },
    {
        "name": "Região Autónoma dos Açores"
    },
    {
        "name": "Serra da Estrela"
    },
    {
        "name": "Tâmega"
    }
],
"links": [
    {
        "source": "Alentejo Central",
        "target": "Alentejo Central",
        "value": "3939"
    },
    {
        "source": "Alentejo Central",
        "target": "Alentejo Litoral",
        "value": "47"
    },
    {
        "source": "Alentejo Central",
        "target": "Algarve",
        "value": "113"
    },
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]esta foto é o que tenho no postgres relativo aos dados que quero mostrar  no sankety

Answer (score 0):

[json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) permite o uso de bitmask para passar várias constantes para este metodo. Testei agora assim:

```
<?php
$array = json_decode('{
"nodes":[
{"name":"Barry"},
{"name":"Frodo"},
{"name":"Elvis"},
{"name":"Sarah"},
{"name":"Alice"}
],
"links":[
{"source":"Barry","target":"Elvis","value":2},
{"source":"Frodo","target":"Elvis","value":2},
{"source":"Frodo","target":"Sarah","value":2},
{"source":"Barry","target":"Alice","value":2},
{"source":"Elvis","target":"Sarah","value":2},
{"source":"Elvis","target":"Alice","value":2},
{"source":"Sarah","target":"Alice","value":4}
]}');

$fp = fopen('json.json', 'w');
fwrite($fp, json_encode($array,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT|JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));
fclose($fp);
```

Dando este resultado:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: {
            "source": "T\u00e2mega",
            "target": "Regi\u00e3o Aut\u00f3noma dos A\u00e7ores",
            "value": "28"
        },
        {
            "source": "T\u00e2mega",
            "target": "Serra da Estrela",
            "value": "4"
        },
        {
            "source": "T\u00e2mega",
            "target": "T\u00e2mega",
            "value": "12920"
        }

Comment: fica com a parte do meio separada e campos desformatados

Comment: Testei agora, mostro o resultado o em cima

Comment: vou por como ficou

Comment: o que pode estar acontecer no meu caso será que tenho a leitura bem feita do php penso que sim

Comment: Exato, igual ao meu. Se quiser um output do json mais costumizado acho que não o conseguirei ajudar.

Comment: Posso perguntar porquê essa necessidade?

Comment: tenho um trabalho sobre d3.js é essa a necessiadade

Comment: Não conheço. Não funciona desta maneira?

Comment: não. amigo tentei meter ate menos dados e nada

Comment: converter esta query para pdo     $nodes = array();
    
    for ($x = 0; $x < mysql_num_rows($query); $x++) {
        $nodes[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
    }

Comment: Como está a agarrar o resultado do json.json? é assim: `d3.json("json.json", function(data) {...` ?

Comment: sim é mas vi que posso chamar directamente o php .

Comment: Sim pode, é só fazer o `echo` do json

Comment: sim foi o que fiz e funciona com o exemplo agora com os meus dados é que não e não sei porque..